# Calculate the probability mass function of the new random variable $Z≡X+Y$

Tags: probability, self-study, joint-distribution

I am having trouble with these. How do I complete the table?

> Consider the random variables $X$ and $Y$ with joint distribution as given below.
>
> ```
>        X 
>      0  1 
> Y 1 .2 .2 
>   2 .5 .1 
>           1
> ```
>
> Calculate the probability mass function of the new random variable $Z≡X+Y$:
>
> $z$___|_____|______|______|_____|
>
> $p(z)$|______|______|______|_____|
>
> Calculate the variance of  $Z$, $V[Z]≡σ_Z^2$ and show that $V[Z]=V[X]+V[Y]+2\rm{cov}[X,Y]$.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: Determine the possible values for $Z$. Is it possible for $Z$ to be equal to $0$? Equal to $1$? Fill the first line. After that, compute, for example, $p(2)=P(Z=2)=P(X=0,Y=2)+P(X=1,Y=1)$. Fill the second line.

Comment: Check the keyword _convolution_.

Comment: @Xi'an Are $X$ and $Y$ independent here?